# Reusability and Extensibility in OOPL

Tags: class, inheritance, polymorphism, reusability, extensibility

I have 3 problems, which are more or less similar.

1. Given a integer array, I want to find the longest continuous subarray, such that the subarray is in increasing order of numbers.
2. Given a integer array, I want to find the longest continuous subarray, such that the subarray have all same numbers.
3. Given a character array, I want to find the longest continuous subarray, such that the subarray have all same characters.

I want to fully exploit concepts of reusability and extensibility in oops. I have implemented some code using templates. I have gave it a try and made a class template for problem 2 and 3 since they both can be done just comparing the ascii value of number or character. But I am not sure how to integrate the code for problem 1? I just want to know how tackle such problems from the perspective of reusability and extensibility using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

[Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to the rescue: you can define an interface that encapsulates the matching strategy, say `SubarrayMatcher` and create two implementations, one that matches "increasing order of values" and another that matches "same values". Your main algorithm can then take the interface as a parameter and call out to it to do the matching.

High-level structure in pseudo-code:

```
Array<T> findLongestSubarray(Array<T> values, SubarrayMatcher<T> matcher);

interface SubarrayMatcher<T>
class IncreasingSubarrayMatcher<T> implements SubarrayMatcher<T>
class ConstantSubarrayMatcher<T> implements SubarrayMatcher<T>
```